# Oracle: how to select data from multiple MSSQL and store into one table on ORACLE?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've got one main server with Oracle DB and 10 MSSQL servers with the same DB structure. I've created DB links for all servers named MSSQL_A, MSSQL_B, MSSQL_C..etc and can get data by executing

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE@MSSQL_A
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE@MSSQL_B
...
```

I created new table `MY_CENTRAL_TABLE` on main/Oracle server having the same structure as `MY_TABLE` on MSSQL servers with additional column identifying the db_link, from which data came from.
Can you help me to develop stored procedure, which will load the data from MY_TABLE@ and insert it into `MY_CENTRAL_TABLE`, where db_link will be passed to the procedure as a parameter?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use dynamic sql:

```
procedure load_from_dblink(dblink_name string) 
is
    sql_statment varchar2(2000);
begin
    sql_statement := "insert into my_central_table select '''||
                      dblink_name||
                      ''', t.* from my_table@'||
                      dblink_name||' t';
    execute immediate sql_statement;
end;
```

Comment: thank you vav! I'm sure I tried very similar syntax, but didn't work.. this works great!